# using dynamic string like

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, left-join, case

I have 2 Tables in SQL server 2008 r2

```
+----+-----------------+
| id | txt             |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | {115467}Ruwan   |
|  2 | {7877878787}pat |
+----+-----------------+
```

and

```
+----+------------+
| id | pid        |
+----+------------+
|  1 |     115467 |
|  2 | 7877878787 |
|  3 |   78787878 |
+----+------------+
```

I need to compare txt of t1 and pid of t2. from t1.txt i need the things inside { only to consider
so my output will be like

```
+----+------------+---------+
| id | pid        | matches |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 |     115467 | yes     |
|  2 | 7877878787 | yes     |
|  3 |   78787878 | no      |
+----+------------+---------+
```

Currently I did the following:

```
$sql='SELECT pid  FROM t2";
//fetch all pid on array and then inside loop
begin loop
$sql1="select * from t1 where txt like %$array_of_pid[$i]%";
```

Is there any efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.pid, (CASE WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END) matches 
FROM temp2 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN temp t2 ON t2.txt LIKE '%{' + CAST(t1.pid AS VARCHAR(10)) + '}%'
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80665/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID |        PID | MATCHES |
|----|------------|---------|
|  1 |     115467 |     yes |
|  2 | 7877878787 |     yes |
|  3 |   78787878 |      no |
```

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
  select t2.pid
  from   t2
  join   t1
  on     t1.txt like '%{' + t2.pid + '}%'
  order
  by     t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY, txt VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @temp (id, txt)
VALUES (1, '{115467}Ruwan'), (2, '{7877878787}pat')

DECLARE @temp2 TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY, pid BIGINT)
INSERT INTO @temp2 (id, pid)
VALUES (1, 115467), (2, 7877878787), (3, 78787878)

SELECT
    id, 
    pid, 
    matches = ISNULL((
        SELECT TOP 1 'yes' 
        FROM @temp t 
        WHERE t.txt LIKE '%' + CAST(t2.pid AS VARCHAR(10)) + '%'
    ), 'no')
FROM @temp2 t2
```

Output -

```
id          pid                  matches
----------- -------------------- -------
1           115467               yes
2           7877878787           yes
3           78787878             no
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select 
t2.id,
t2.pid,
CASE    
    when t1.txt is NULL THEN 'no' 
    ELSE 'YES' 
END AS matches 
  from   t2
  left join   t1
  on     (t1.txt like '%{'+t2.pid+'}%')
```

result

```
id  pid         matches
1   115467      YES
2   7877878787  YES
3   78787878    no
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Code can look like this

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.pid, CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%' + t2.pid + '%', t1.txt) > 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS matches 
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

**EDIT**
If you are scared that there might be mathcing characters outside of the curleys, you can change your PATINDEX to

```
PATINDEX('%{' + t2.pid + '}%', t1.txt) > 0
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it could match on 787878 and 7878787. You probably want to use the curly brackets as 'boundaries'. Also, why are you joining on the `id` columns of each table? I don't think they relate.

Comment: Sorry, I missed an Argument in PATINDEX. fixed it. @Nicarus the join is on `id` and not `pid` which means that it cannot match the way you proposed

Comment: I didn't propose you join it on `pid`. Based on the question, I don't think you can join `t1.id = t2.id`, which is what you are doing in your answer.